# Selenium not finding elements in Firefox when run via Jenkins

Tags: selenium, firefox, jenkins, nightwatch.js, geckodriver

I have a suite of Nightwatch tests that I regularly run across multiple browsers on Windows 10

Recently selenium has been unable to locate any elements when running Firefox through a local instance of Jenkins that is run as a Windows service. Firefox uses geckodriver webdriver in Nightwatch.

Test run flawlessly when run locally via cmd or git bash etc.

Anyone have any idea what may be causing this issue.

Versions installed:

1. Geckodriver v.0.19.1
2. Firefox v.57.0.4
3. Nightwatch v0.9.19
4. Selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1

Failure trace snippet

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  3804

[Widgets\ C36310 Widgets Available On Dispatch] Test Suite
==============================================================

Running:  C36310 Widgets Available On Dispatch
 √ Details & Strings Loaded
 √ Home Page Element Selectors Loaded
 × Check For Visibility Of Sign In Banner.  - expected "visible" but got: 
"not visible"
    at Object.exports.command (C:\Users\matthewf\Documents\master-ui\workspace\Workspaces\master_eld\src\resources\custom_commands\login.js:22:6)
```

Comment: did you confirm the version of firefox and gecko driver on the Jenkins machine matches the versions you have locally, and those versions are compatible with each other?

Comment: set your DISPLAY

Comment: Update the question with your code trials, relevant `HTML` and the error stack trace please.

Comment: Jenkins is being run on my local machine so same versions.
Updated question with relevant snippets

Comment: We still need the code of the test, the HTML of the element and how you are calling the test.